# tf linker error

Tags: ros, pointcloud, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a linker issue while using tf library. Here is my callback. Without this only line in the callback there is NO linker error. Please, find below the linker error itself.

```
void callback (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
  listener->waitForTransform("/world_base_link", (*input).header.frame_id, (*input).header.stamp, ros::Duration(5.0));
 ...
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "subscriber");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/kinect2/depth/points", 1, callback);
  ros::spin ();
}
```

Linker error:

```
Linking CXX executable range_image_border_extraction
CMakeFiles/range_image_border_extraction.dir/range_image_border_extraction.cpp.o: In function `callback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
range_image_border_extraction.cpp:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `tf::Transformer::waitForTransform(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Time const&, ros::Duration const&, ros::Duration const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [range_image_border_extraction] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/range_image_border_extraction.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project(range_image_border_extraction)

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg tf pcl_ros)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(range_image_border_extraction range_image_border_extraction.cpp)
target_link_libraries(range_image_border_extraction ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(range_image_border_extraction ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Any ideas how to resolve this linker error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197132/tf-linker-error/) by [Andrii Matviienko](https://answers.ros.org/users/12181/andrii-matviienko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2014-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2014-11-10**:
Please edit your question to include your CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding tf to find_package in CMakeLists.txt solved the problem.
I had:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)
```

Should be:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg tf)
```

---

Originally posted by [Andrii Matviienko](https://answers.ros.org/users/12181/andrii-matviienko/) with karma: 56 on 2014-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0